# elements removal from a list in tcl

Tags: list, tcl

How to remove every even index elemnt form a list in tcl? I used

```
    for {set i 0} {$i <[llength $a]} {incr i} {
    if {[expr $i % 2] == 0} {
     lreplace $a [lindex $a $i] [lindex $a $i] 
    }
```

but how to update the variable using lreplace whenever i delete an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using your technique you need to change `incr` command:

```
% set a {a b c e f g h}
a b c e f g h
% for {set i 1} { $i < [llength $a] } {incr i 2} {lappend c [lindex $a $i]}
% puts $c
b e g
%
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably much easier to create a new list and add there the elements you want. Below the foreach will travel the list as pairs and append the first one to the new list. This works also with lists with odd number of elements. The last time value of j will just be empty.

```
set a "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"                                          

set result []                                                        
foreach {i j} $a {                                                   
    lappend result $i                                                
}                                                                    

puts $result
```

The result will be

```
0 2 4 6 8 10
```

Note that most list related commands in TCL take the name of the list (e.g lreplace A 0 0), not the value (<strike>lreplace $A 0 0</strike>)

Comment: The `lreplace` commmand takes a list value and returns the updated list value (using copy-on-write semantics under the hood); it doesn't take a variable containing a list.